# Safari and Chrome can't handle newly added element

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari

I have a problem, please help.

I have a template like this:

```
<div id="dad">
     <div id="son" style="width: 100%">
     some code
     </div>
</div>
```

then I have an action of expand the dad-div by jQuery animation

```
$('#dad').animation({'width': 800px}, 500);
```

on this moment, the son and the dad both 800px width, which is fine for me.

But strange things happened on safari and chrome when I use ajax fetch a new son element from server and replace the old one:

```
    $.get(url, extraData, function(response) {
        $('#son').hide('slide', null, 500, function(){
            $('#son').replaceWith(response);
            $('#son').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
        });
    });
```

The expand dad script still work, but here are some differences:
On IE and FireFox, the dad and son was resized simultaneously, so the effect seems smooth
and good. But on the Safari and Chrome this process is divided in two steps, first expand dad to 800px with animation, and then make the son to 800px with a "jump" change, and this "jump" make later process wrong.

I feel IE and FireFox handled this in a right fashion, could any one help me fix the Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have `replace` method, it seems you want to use  `replaceWith` method.

```
$('#son').replaceWith(response);
```

Note that `replaceWith` replaces element with another element, if you only want to change the content of an element, you can use `html` method.

```
$('#son').html(function(){
   return $(response).html();
});
```

Comment: oh yes, It is "replaceWith", fixed. and what i really want to know is why the "son" div is not expanded with "dad" div.

Comment: @HetfieldJoe This is related to CSS, does newly appended element have `style="width: 100%"`?

Comment: yes it is, I wrote style inside the tag just for handy here. actually it defined in other css file. and the new "son" is totally the same as the old one, except inner text.

Comment: @HetfieldJoe So why not using `html` method? try the second method.